# Not able to install react native in macbook

Tags: react-native, installation

[image]This issue occurs...

When I am trying to install react native-command line interface in my MacBook pro.

I am not behind any proxy but it still asks me to remove proxy

Here is a screenshot of my internet preferences.

[image: This issue occurs]

I have also tried to remove files from usr/local/bin/npm

Comment: Can you please share your node and npm versions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your network connection. Is not related to React Native or NPM.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I tried it with different networks , also tried with mobile hotspot, i am able to install npm, watch man etc. but when i write the command to install react cli , it throws this error.

Comment: is there anyway to check if my network is stoping the same, because i am able to do all other stuff but not this.

Comment: What I see in your Error logs. It looks is just a connection timeout. Probably if you try it again other time it will work. I think your connection with the server was just too slow.

Comment: Does it need `sudo`? Because it's installing globally, could it be a permission problem?

Comment: I don't think is permission related problem because the error message would tell it.

Comment: @SomethingOn please help me to understand more about permission as this is the only thing i havent tried yet..Thanks

Comment: Sometimes when doing an npm install with `-g`, which means `global` (basically installing it on the machine rather than in a project) it has to access directories that may be owned by the system, not the current user. `sudo` is kinda of hack to make it work. Following these instructions might be better: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions. Using `sudo` in this case is like setting folder permissions to 777, it'll work, but isn't necessarily the best idea ;)